# How to achieve Two Way data binding in native GWT?

Tags: gwt

We have been using GWT for around 4 years now. One of the most often discussed features missing in native GWT is data binding. Reading across AngularJs another Google offering, i came across http://devgirl.org/2013/03/21/fun-with-angularjs/ . I do not wish to use GXT or any other third party tools. I also wish to avoid generator related solution.

1. **Is there any way this will ever be implementable in pure native GWT?**
2. **Is there any specific reason why GWT cannot provide this out of the BOX?**

Comment: is this the right place for this question?

Comment: Anywhere else i can query this on stackexchange? GWT tag in programmers.stackexchange.com is hardly noticed with only 15 queries!!!! http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gwt

Comment: The example in the devgirl post you posted is already achieved in GWT. If you bind a variable to many places on your screen and you update that variable, its new value is reflected in all the places that reference it. Out of the box.

Comment: You are describing GWT's Editor feature. Editor's have huge drawback in terms of use with CellTable/DataGrid and also do not support 2 way binding. "We" can invoke edit to copy values from model to view and  flush to copy view to model ( how do you wire this automagically )

Comment: @SSR I didn't downvote your question, that was someone else that agreed with my comment. I'm just pointing out that you are asking about/suggesting features in the core implementation of GWT, don't you think that this question is more appropriate for the GWT Steering Committee? I mean, if I have a question about core features in Java I just go to the JSR regarding that feature instead of starting a broad discussion in a Q&A website...

Comment: :) i do not mind the downvote as long as people describe their reason. I ran into angular js and above blog via GWT's Ray Cromwells work on - https://github.com/cromwellian/angulargwt

Comment: I have been experimenting with manually implementing 2-way data-binding in the Editor framework, and it's not that bad. Simply a call to `editorDriver.flush()` followed by `editorDriver.accept(new Refresher())`. Once I realized that the Editor framework implemented the Visitor pattern, I realized I could do anything with them that I could do with trees! I have been meaning to dive into the generators for the Editor framework to see if there is a way to achieve 2-way data-binding automatically, but just haven't had the time yet.

Comment: The 'big deal' with 'observer' data binding (as opposed to the editor frameworks 'flow sync' data binding) is that you need each setter on the model to fire an event (so you can't possibly use this with RequestFactory, and it gets gross to use with AutoBeans), and that you need every possible editor to fire "I've changed something!" events. Especially as you start customizing things like grids and tree, you don't always want to flush each and every change back into the model right away, so each approach is good at things the other isn't.

Comment: Having an option is not bad :) . Editor framework "flow sync" is a suspect for complex screens with editable grids. We just gave up after 3 months of POC.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [GWT Pectin](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-pectin/)?

I have used it successfully in a larger project some time ago.

Comment: I do not see any active development in GWT pectin since 2010 ( 3 years ) and it would not have taken into consideration new gwt features at all!!!

Comment: You are right! I asked the developer once to produce a new release, which he promptly did. But it's definitely not being actively developed. However, it answers your question by providing an actual implementation. Personally, I very much liked the expressiveness of the library when I used it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try HexaBinding, which is non invasive and only focused on data binding. Here is the link : https://github.com/ltearno/hexa.tools/blob/master/hexa.binding/README.md

It works with pure Java, GWT and will soon work also with Android and JavaFX. It may even work with J2Objc but not sure yet...

Answer (score 0):

I read the post you mention on devgirl about AngularJS. In that post the "2 way data binding" refers to the property of the code to reflect automatically on the view the changes that occurs to the data that the view is currently displaying.

This is achieved in GWT since version 2.1 with the [Cell Widgets](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets)

In the first paragraph of the Cell Widgets documentation I linked above it is clearly stated that:

> A cell widget can accept data from any type of data source. The data
>   model handles asynchronous updates as well as push updates. **When you
>   change the data, the view is automatically updated.**

If you want to do in GWT something as basic as the [example](http://embed.plnkr.co/dECGEtvMvcMwabCP1IoZ/preview) in the devGirl post you need to write a onKeyup handler (in AngularJS you should write a [Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) to this purpose) that would copy what you entered to the linked label. Something like this:

```
...
final TextBox nameField = new TextBox();
final Label enteredName = new Label("");
...
    public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
        enteredName.setText(nameField.getText());
    }
...
```